# Managing the multiple function with 5 parameters

Tags: python, function

I've simplified the original code. At first I thought this code would show me only the apply(a1,y,c1,d1,e1) part, but it was executed by the order it is written below. Beside of cramming the whole x and y into apply(a1,y,...e1), what should I do to only get the result of apply(a1,y,...e1) while ignoring x = apply(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1) and y = apply(a1,x,c1,d1,e1)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
def apply(a,b,c,d,e):

x = apply(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1)
y = apply(a1,x,c1,d1,e1)
apply(a1,y,c1,d1,e1)
```

Comment: *"what should I do to get the wanted result"* → and, what is the wanted result? and the input? logic? expected output?

Comment: Just finished editing

Comment: still it is not clear what you want? ignore the second parameter? only sometimes? what would be the logic then? and you should provide a [mre] and explain more specifically what the function is trying to achieve or what you want to achieve, currently I only see three function calls and in two cases the return value is assigned to variables

Comment: What is your result? Where do you want to get?

Comment: As it's very unclear I would sugesst you to rewrite the apply function to give directly the good result.
As it seems the only re-use of inputs is the second one. but without the code of the apply function all is deduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is unclear, but if I guess correctly, you're wondering how to apply a function on itself using only one parameter, and without intermediate variables.

One easy answer is:

```
apply(a1,apply(a1,apply(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1),c1,d1,e1),c1,d1,e1)
```

but this is not very convenient.

One can get rid of the other parameters by defining a wrapper function (or using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) if the last parameter is used).

```
def apply(a,b,c,d,e):
    # dummy process
    return a+b+c+d+e

a,c,d,e = 1,3,4,5
f = lambda x: apply(a, x, c, d, e)

f(f(f(2)))
# 41

(1+(1+(1+2+3+4+5)+3+4+5)+3+4+5)
# 41
```

This is still cumbersome if there are many iterations.

In this case, a solution is to use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,_: f(x), range(3), 2)
# 41

# checking that it works on 1000 iterations:
assert reduce(lambda x,_: f(x), range(1000), 2) == (1+3+4+5)*1000+2
```